# Style of writing inside a manual

Tags: writing, style

I would like to ask about the style of English that is used (or has to be used) for a technical manual.

In other languages it seems to be different, but I have read many technical books in English and they use things like

> **Let's** say that we have a task space position A and a task space position B. **We** want to compute the joint states for each of those positions, which **we** can feed to joint-space controllers to move the arm 
>   (Programming Robots with ROS)

As you can see, they use "Let's" or "we" quite often.

Is this style of writing acceptable for a technical manual? (for example an installation manual?) Or is it too "familiar"?

Comment: I'm confused. You say that you've read many technical books that use that style. If many technical books *do* use it, then surely it must be acceptable at least some of the time.

Comment: I am making the distinction between technical books (that *do* use that style) and manuals specifically. I am not sure about manuals

Comment: I may be old-fashioned, but I confess that this informal, chatty style in this context makes me cringe. It sounds like the sort of language a teacher would use to first-graders, and sounds patronising to me. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: I rather like the style. "One" sounds very stiff to me. There was a question recently about the use of "we" in a mathematics paper.  https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/249670/whats-the-difference-of-the-subject-being-one-and-we-in-math-articles/249672#249672